# Sending email from workflow concatinated with task id

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, development, designer-workflow

I have a custom web part that approves a task.

I want to send an email from the workflow that includes the link of the web part and task id. So that the moment I click that link the web part will be shown populated with the values in a list.

Comment: Is that webpart only web part on your page? And is it a kind of form which show details about the task?

Comment: Also does your webpart contains any custom code to retrieve data based on task id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Approving a task or similar actions in theory means you are updating a list item.
And each list item has a unique ID, and it can be easily retrieved in a SharePoint workflow.

From your question, I understand you have 3 requirements

**1.** Send an email from a workflow. Which is pretty simple just insert an action `Send an Email` from ribbon

[image]

**2.** To get the link of a webpart, I am assuming your webpart must be placed on some page. And designer workflow do provide us OOB properties which helps us to make URLs

[image]

**3.** Get ID of the TASK. Workflows return us the ID of the current item. And you get it as below.

[image]

> Note: In screen shots 2 and 3 the lookup pop up is opened when you
>   click the `Add or change Lookup` button

So this is how you get the URL and ID of a current item in a workflow. Also we can concatenate the ID in the URL as a query string based on your requirement.

I hope this helps!!